# Automating Build Process of c++ code using RTC and jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, ibm-jazz, ibm-streams

I would like to know if we can automate the build, whenever a developer deliver changes and send him the build report.

I am looking for RTC commands which I can used in Jenkins. Till now, I am able to connect to RTC, load the stream and build locally through Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to define a workspace on the target stream (the one where delivers occur)

Then, as described in the [JENKINS Team-Concert Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Team+Concert+Plugin):

> - Find the "Build Triggers" section.
> - Check the "Poll SCM" check box to poll for incoming changes to the build workspace.
> - Enter a schedule.  Click the help button beside the "Schedule" field to get help with the syntax.

You can then check every 5 minutes of new change sets have been delivered, and trigger your Jenkins build that way (ie, polling for changes).

---

For the mail part, Independently of RTC, You can use the [JENKINS Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) in order to send an email after each build.
See for example "[How to send Email at every build with Jenkins](http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/articles-jenkins-email)"

[image: http://www.nailedtothex.org/articles-img/jenkins/email/email.png]

You would receive an email with a link to the Jenkins job report page.

Comment: Yes, firstly I would like to know how to automatically build RTC. Please help with that

Comment: @RaviYadav You mention in your question "I am able to connect to RTC, load the stream and build locally through Jenkins." All what was missing was the email part.

Comment: @RaviYadav Did you follow https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Team+Concert+Plugin? What is missing?

Comment: But that build was done on timely basis. I want to trigger build as soon as change set or snapshot is delivered.

Comment: I am looking for configure from RTC side which trigger Jenkins Jobs like it is done in Git. I appreciate your solution, however, this will lead to burden on server.

Comment: Could you help me in understanding the CI architecture? I want to automate the build process which has RTC, Coverity, Jenkins.

Comment: @RaviYadav That would be best as a separate question, but as far as I know, https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/JazzScmWithJenkinsPlugin is the best source.